# Failed to load resource without exception detail

Tags: android, android-glide

I use Glide to load a URL of image to image view, like this:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.image_place_holder).error(R.drawable.image_place_holder);

Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
           .load(url)
           .listener(new RequestListener() {
                     @Override
                     public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            // Log the GlideException here (locally or with a remote logging framework):
                            Log.e(TAG, "Load failed", e);
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            // You can also log the individual causes:
                            for (Throwable t : e.getRootCauses()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Caused by", t);
                            }
                            // Or, to log all root causes locally, you can use the built in helper method:
                            e.logRootCauses(TAG);

                            return false; // Allow calling onLoadFailed on the Target.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Object resource, Object model, Target target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
   .apply(requestOptions)
   .into(imageView);
```

But Glide throw an exception in onLoadFailed() and show the place holder image instead:

> W/Glide: Load failed for https://abc.xyz/image.png with size [736x388]
>
> class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
>
> TAG : Load failed
>
> class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource

You can see the exception has no causes, and can't print stack trace.

[image]

I try to use the Picasso library or change to another URL, it works!
But I can't understand what happen with the image link. Can you explain this problem here?

Comment: did you get an answer to this one?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille I think there an error with cloud image server config. Some photo can't be display, even if when I paste it to Skype, there's no thumbnail too.

Comment: i see, Thanks alot for the clarification